# Intuition behind the $\| \cdot \|_p$-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

The norm $\| \cdot \|_1$ measures the area under the absolute value of the function. But what is the intuition behind measuring the area under the $p$-th power of the absolute value? What kind of information does that give about the function? How can it be interpreted that a function is in $L^p$ but not in $L^q $ for $p \neq q$?

Comment: $L^p$ is an analog of the usual metric for $\mathbb R^n$.  Spaces of functions are useful to use when we study problems where the solution is a function, such as a differential equation.  Advice: if you have never seen uses for $L^p$ spaces in your studies, then don't worry about them.  Maybe someday you will see such uses.

Comment: @GEdgar I know that. I've seen uses for $L^p$ spaces in my study, this is not what the question is asking about.